# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BannerPosition' could not be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Assets\Scripts\BannerAd.cs(7,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BannerPosition' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

[SerializeField] BannerPosition _bannerPosition;
```

nothing i copied this cod from video

Comment: What version of Unity Ads do you use? If it is 4.3.0, then update to a newer version. There's a bug with BannerPosition in 4.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

BannerPosition should be declared as a Class (a script), maybe you missed it in the video or you didn't reach when it's going to be created.

Answer (score 0):

The UnityEngine.Advertisements asmdef doesn't compile because you probably don't fulfil the define constraints.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-should-i-install-unity-ads-in-my-game-asset-store-package-package-manager-or-services-window.699005/
Look at this thread and start your package installation over.